# Using Perl to replace a string in only a certain line of file

Tags: bash, perl, edit

I have a script that I am using for a large scale find and replace.  When a match is found in a particular file, I record the file name, and the line number.

What I want to do is for each file name, line number pair, change a string from `<foo>` to `<bar>` on only that line of the file.

In my shell script, I am executing a find and replace command on the file given the line number...

```
run=`perl -pi -e "s/$find/$replace/ if $. = $lineNum" $file`
```

This however I believe has been ignoring the `$. = $lineNum` and just does the `s/$find/$replace/` on the whole file, which is really bad.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: `=` is assignment; `==` is comparison.

Comment: $&#@..  How did I not see this before

Comment: A second pair of eyes helps … it's the way the brain works, not spotting the obvious.  It's why pair programming is a good way of working; it's also why code reviews are a very good idea (though in this case, you're having problems getting to the point where the code would be reviewed).

Comment: It is also one of those things that `strict` and `warnings` highlights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using assignment `=` instead of comparison `==`.

Use:

```
perl -pi -e "s/$find/$replace/ if $. == $lineNum" $file
```

where there are some caveats about the content of `$find`, `$replace` and `$lineNum` that probably aren't going to be a problem.  The caveats are issues such as `$find` cannot contain a slash; `$replace` can't contain a slash either; `$lineNum` needs to be a line number; beware other extraneous extra characters that could confuse the code.

I don't see why you'd want to capture the standard output of the Perl process when it writes to the file, not to standard output.  So, the assignment to `run` is implausible.  And if it is necessary, you would probably be better off using `run=$(perl …)` with the `$()` notation in place of `` `…` ``.